# Fatal error: [] operator not supported for strings multiple delete using PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have this code that is supposed to delete all rows whose checkbox was checked (multiple delete using checkboxes).

```
if (isset($_POST['del'])) {

    $stmt = $db->prepare("DELETE FROM `$tbl_name` WHERE id=:id");
    $stmt->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $ids = array();
    foreach ($_POST['del'] as $pval) {
    $ids[] = (int)$pval;
    $ids = implode(',',$ids);
    $stmt->execute();
    }
    echo '<h1>Entries deleted.</h1>';
}
```

this is the form generation code:

```
echo '<td><input type="checkbox" name="del[]" value="' . (int)$row['id'] . '"></td>';
```

Everything works fine if single checkbox was checked, or single delete.
But for multiple checkboxes, it results to a fatal error:

```
Fatal error: [] operator not supported for strings in
```

Anything I missed?

Comment: Is the `$row` variable really an array ?

Comment: @FabienMénager AFAIK sir yes, it came from this: $db->query("SELECT * FROM `$tbl_name` ORDER BY `id`") as $row

Comment: Just for future readers - we assume `$table_name` has been validated from a whitelist of acceptable values (an array for example), and does not directly result from user input, which would be vulnerable to SQL injection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fatal error results from this line, as you overwrite the array `$ids` with the string result of `implode()` but on the next loop iteration attempt to append to it again with `[]`.

```
$ids = implode(',',$ids);
```

That should be removed. You have already bound `$id`, so you can just `execute()` in the loop with `$id`.

```
if (isset($_POST['del'])) {
    // Prepare the statement before the loop
    $stmt = $db->prepare("DELETE FROM `$tbl_name` WHERE id=:id");
    $stmt->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);

    // Execute the prepared statement in the loop with the ids from $_POST
    // This is all you need, since $id is bound 
    foreach ($_POST['del'] as $id) {
      $stmt->execute();
    }
    echo '<h1>Entries deleted.</h1>';
}
```

That method uses a loop. You could also execute a single statement with positional parameters if you bound each value from `$_POST['del']` with its own `?`. That is more work, and probably only worth it if you will be deleting *lots* of items in each loop.

Comment: bindParam should also be in the foreach loop. Because now you'll get a undefined $id. Or is that my misconception?

Comment: @Luceos: You actually won't.  `bindParam` takes a reference to a variable :)